# Rails 4 before_action for HTTP Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I have a before action on a create method like so:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end

#on some view while logged out, a user may see a form like so
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  # some post data
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to be a logged out user and view a form that allows the guest to post.  When the guest clicks the form submit button, I would like it to render the login form and after successful login to proceed to the create method.

Everything is working up until the point of proceeding to the posts#create method.  Instead, it is rendering root_path. I am unsure if this is part of the desired functionality of before_action or not.

So, is it possible to have a before_action continue to a HTTP Post method with the original params from the form?

Comment: How are you persisting the post data? If you render the login form, you've created a new instance of the controller / model, which means you'll lose your `post` data. How are you persisting it?

Comment: You are correct.  It is not persisting at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise, you could add something like this to your `ApplicationController`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to request.referrer
end
```

This will ensure that every time after signin, you refer to the previous page.

Comment: This is, of course, considering the OP is using Devise ;)

Comment: I am using Devise.  If I use request.referrer, it will redirect back to the last page visited. I'm not too big into the referrer method because if I direct a user to login, but they actually need to sign up.